# Virtualbox bridged networking on OVH server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I can't get that working even thou I configured it few times on other machines. Probably it's problem with something ovh-specific, or maybe I just twisted myself hard enough by now.

Clean install of 12.04 (changed kernel to normal from ovh one), installed vbox from oracle repos, have phpvirtualbox set up and working. Machines create fine, import fine, but... networking problem.

When VM set up as NAT - can access network, but it's very slow. First ping to whatever always timout. Never seen such thing...

When in bridged networking mode no connectivity at all. I have additional external ip for VM and it's set up exactly like OVH requires (I mean /etc/network/interfaces on guest).

I also changed MAC for this ip in ovh panel.

I think problem is with vbox config on host. First of all when I want to choose adapter for VM (in bridged mode) there is eht0 and eth1, while on host there is only eth0 at the moment - how can that be?

As far as I know vbox should work out of the box, but this is not going to happen for me.

Can you please give me some hint where to look for? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question :) It's been a year now, and I know the answer, so maybe it will be helpful to you all :)

OVH setting is a bit weird, that's why it takes people so much time and effort to set it up properly :)

So you set your VM into bridged networking and in your /etc/network/interfaces (on the VM) you do something like this:

Let's assume:

- your host ip is: AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
- you want to give your VM ip address of EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH
- you will use open DNS like 208.67.222.222
- you have already added/registered VM's MAC address in OVH panel to the ip address chosen for VM (if you use Virtualbox, just choose type: ovh)

Configuration itself:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH
   netmask 255.255.255.255
   broadcast EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH
   dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222
   post-up route add AAA.BBB.CCC.254 dev eth0
   post-up route add default gw AAA.BBB.CCC.254
   post-down route del default gw AAA.BBB.CCC.254
   post-down route del AAA.BBB.CCC.254 dev eth0
```

This article helped me a lot [link](https://binaryimpulse.com/2014/08/ovh-ip-failover-vm-configuration/)